# Getting substring from NSString

Tags: ios, nsstring

I have a `NSString` which looks like this:

```
http://fiskltd.com/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/thumb_09afd9f041af34fb0cffec1e0b1222e8.jpg
```

And I need extract from that this string:

> thumb_09afd9f041af34fb0cffec1e0b1222e8.jpg

I will have lots of such strings, so I won't know the number of characters and how many of them will the name of the picture. Can anyone tell me how to extract the name of picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be the best solution in your case will be `[NSString lastPathComponent]`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
NSString *originalString = @"http://fiskltd.com/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/thumb_09afd9f041af34fb0cffec1e0b1222e8.jpg";
NSString *filename = [originalString lastPathComponent];
```

Apple docs [here.](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-lastPathComponent)